# How to replicate this drop down menu like facebook?

Tags: ios

I want to add dropdown menu like this one but I can't figure out which would be the best approach.

[image: 1]

I'm not asking for code, just for some advices or helpful links.
Thank you.

Comment: It's a combination of an overlay view (to darken the background), a view with a custom path (to have the small arrow + the rounded edges), and a bunch of subviews. Something quite basic IMHO, what blocks you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use kxmenu. it create daynamic menu

https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link for you, but I can explain how I see it.

You can create your own `UIWindow` object, then put `UIView` with blur effect on it, and on top of it put static `UITableView`. Then make your new `UIWindow` key and visible.

So your view hierarchy will look like: Old `UIWindow` -> New `UIWindow` -> Blured background view -> `UITableView`

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would procede creating a custom UIView, with a tableView inside, and a transparent background.

Than when you need it you add it to your current view. It's a similar principle I used for a bubble menu I created.

Take a look, there is a lot of code you can reuse:

https://github.com/scamps88/ASBubbleMenu